# How to update solved critical issues in sonarcube

Tags: sonarqube

i am new programmer using sonarcube.
i have corrected the critical issues that were highlighted in sonarcube. so now the problem is  even though after updating , sonarcube show the older code, not the one that i changed. What cud b the reason. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does SonarQube (not cube) still show critical issues that you have corrected or does it show only the previous version of the code ?

You should check that you have put the new version of the code in the right place, this is most probably where is the problem.

Regards.

Comment: thanks!! the problem is been solved....i didn't refreshed the server... once i made the changes in the code....so refreshing the server gave me the updated status of the issues!!